# Do disabled people have less of a right to their medical information than legal adults?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, discrimination

Consider a disabled person who is a legal adult. If his or her doctor wants to withhold medical information from them:

*Does the doctor have more of a right to do so simply because that person is physically or mental disabled (paraplegic, autistic, etc)?*

*And if so, does it matter how high functioning or how independent that person is?*

*And could any of this be a product of the constitution?*

Comment: This seems more of a legal question than political one

Comment: @DVK Not to those with a disability. Whilst we seem to be permanent froth about guns, sex and taxes; this sort of question is as valid as the law/politics nexus of, say, state laws on burqas.

Answer (score 3):

The standard used to decide questions like this is [**Mentally Competent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/mental+capacity).  [This article](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2001/0715/p299.html) from the American Academy of Family Physicians says

> **If the patient lacks the capacity for decisionmaking, a determination of surrogacy will be necessary.** In the best-case scenario, the patient may have previously appointed an agent; in the worst-case scenario, the court may need to become involved. (The discussion of surrogacy is too broad for this article, but it has been well-covered elsewhere.) If the patient does not have an advance directive or health care proxy, the surrogate will need to make decisions based on principles of “substituted judgment”(what the patient would have decided) or “best interest” (what the surrogate judges to be best for the patient).

Being a legal adult just means you're over 18.  It doesn't mean that you're actually *competent* to act as an adult, although the default assumption is that you are.  If your doctor thinks you're incompetent (in the legal form, not the insulting one), then they find someone who *is* competent to make decisions for you.  This has nothing to do with "rights", and is most definitely not covered in the Constitution.

Comment: What if it's that someone has high functioning autism. They need some help for dependence, but they are highly intelligent and everyone knows they aren't crazy. Could the doctor lie to an autistic or is that not sever enough of a situation? What if the autistics parents are involved?

Comment: @user3695903 - That's up to the doctor involved, and *that particular doctor's* assessment at *that particular time*.  Finding a different doctor or suing for malpractice are both ways to dispute that doctor's decision.  But as [one paper said](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1079581/), `No decision as to whether or not a refusal of treatment should be respected can or should be made by means of a diagram or a formula.`  In other words, **it's a judgement call.**   I suggest reading the article I linked to in the answer, which discusses when and how doctors make that decision.